# CentOS Installation display misalignment

Tags: centos, display

Disclaimer: I've searched around a bit for a solution but I really don't know where to start. I've reset the display and tried another display with no fix.

I'm installing CentOS 7 minimal from a USB stick I 'burnt' with [YUMI USB Multiboot Creator](http://pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/)

It's as if the scaling is way off for the displays I'm using (one, a TV at 1080p over HDMI, and one a monitor at 1650x1050 over DVI) and it's cutting off the right quarter of the installation screen.

[image: Screenshot attached here]

Comment: Try to specify an alternative resolution with [`inst.resolution`](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Installation_Guide/chap-anaconda-boot-options.html)

Comment: Used Ctrl-Alt-F1 to get a terminal and looked through the logs to discover it was a driver issue, it was displaying 640x480 but outputting it as 1080p. No resolution options worked.

Ended up doing a text based install. Thanks anyway.